# Executar uma query ao clicar em resultado de outra query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de colunas do meu banco de dados:
account_id, name e aparencia.
Imagem:
http://puu.sh/gYLVL/4083073484.png

Eu possuia o seguinte código anteriormente:

```
<font size="3">Por favor digite o nome do personagem que deseja Resetar a Aparencia</font>
<br><br><br>
<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form3" class="formulario">
<label for="senha">Nome do Personagem:</label>
<input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" size="40" />
<br /><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Resetar Aparencia!" style="cursor:pointer;">

</form>
```

E o seu PHP:

```
<?php
$conexao =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","wamp","ragnarok");
    if(trim($_POST["nome"]) == "")
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><img src='images/erro.png'> Por favor digite o nome do personagem!</div>";
        exit(); 
    }

    if (strlen($_POST["nome"]) < 4)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><img src='images/erro.png'> Nome curto demais!</div>";
        exit(); 
    }

    if (strlen($_POST["nome"]) > 23)
    {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><img src='images/erro.png'> Nome grande demais!</div>";
        exit(); 
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `char` WHERE name = '".$_POST["nome"]."'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
    $campo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    if ($_POST['nome'] === $campo['name']) {
        $query = "UPDATE `char` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE name = '".$_POST["nome"]."'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

        $Uid = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><img src='images/check.png'> Aparencia resetada com sucesso!</div>";    
    }
    else
    {   

            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><img src='images/erro.png'> Nome do personagem inválido!</div>";


    }

    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Bom, esse código funcionava perfeitamente, pegava o nome do jogador digitado no campo do formulário, verificava se condizia com o nome do banco de dados e atualizava cada campo com o seu valor.
Porém, eu estou tentando trocar o método, ao invés da pessoa ter que digitar o nome do personagem, eu gostaria que a págna listasse todos os personagens que a pessoa possui e que quando a pessoa clicasse no nome dele, executasse a query que troca os valores dos campos.
Ou seja, mesmo código só que ao invés de input para o nome, listar os nomes como botões.
A listagem dos personagens e aplicação de um botão para cada um é facil, eu ja consegui ficando com este código:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="ajax_form3" class="formulario">

<table class="vertical-table th">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="4"><b>Escolha o personagem que deseja resetar a aparência</b></font></th>
    </tr>';
$idconta = $_SESSION['account_id'];
$sql = "SELECT name FROM `char` WHERE account_id = '$idconta' order by `char_id` ASC";
$limite = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
$name = $sql['name'];
    echo '
<tr>
      <td>
      <br>
      <button style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size:3; cursor:pointer;" class="botao" id="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

O problema agora é, como faço para quando a pessoa clicar em um botão com o nome do personagem, alterar o banco de dados na linha daquele nome a alterar a coluna aparencia para 1? Se possível eu gostaria de continuar usando o método dentro do form, pois ele retorna através do ajax uma mensagem de sucesso sem a necessidade de recarregar a página.

Código atual:

```
<table class="vertical-table th">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="4"><b>Escolha o personagem que deseja resetar a aparência</b></font></th>
    </tr>';
$idconta = $_SESSION['account_id'];
$sql = "SELECT name FROM `char` WHERE account_id = '$idconta' order by `char_id` ASC";
$limite = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
$name = $sql['name'];
    echo '
<tr>
      <td>
      <br>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size:3; cursor:pointer;"><a href="alteraraparencia.php?id="'.$sql['name'].'">'.$name.'</a></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$conexao =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","wamp","ragnarok");
mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE `char` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE name = " . $_GET['name'])
    or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
?>
```

Comment: Você quer mudar o valor da coluna "aparência" quando a pessoa clicar no nome? E para que valor seria mudado? De onde você tiraria? Como você não especificou mais detalhes de como gostaria que fosse essa atualização (sem atualizar a página / redirecionando), fica difícil indicar alguma coisa.

Comment: Exatamente, mudar o valor de aparencia quando a pessoa clicar no nome! O valor seria mudado de 0 para 1 no caso.  Essa é justamente minha dúvida, como vou pegar o valor desse botão que tem o nome da pessoa e executar a query? Se fosse um campo de texto dava para pegar pelo método $_POST mas como é um botao como eu pego este valor?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o problema? Não esqueça de aceitar alguma.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta foi editada e mostra que são vários problemas. Na verdade toda pergunta está comprometida.

Você tem dois grandes problemas, entre vários outro pequenos que eu nem vou tentar resolver.

O primeiro grande problema é que você não está listando os personagens. Como a pergunta original não é sobre isto, não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isto. Abra outra pergunta para resolver este problema.

O segundo é o que vou focar porque era a intenção original da pergunta.

---

Para listar os itens tem que colocar um *link* para este nome e chamar outra página para mostrá-lo. Não vou nem reclamar do estilo antigo do seu HTML. Assim:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#009900" size="3">
    <a href="mostraitem.php?id=' . $linha['account_id']. '>'.$name.'</a></font></p></td>
```

Como você não colocou muitos detalhes da tabela, não posso mostrar mais detalhes também. Como eu disse acima, abra outra pergunta para resolver este problema.

Feito isto, na página que executará a atualização você fará assim, de forma mais ingênua que é o jeito que provavelmente está fazendo:

```
$conexao =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root","wamp","ragnarok");
mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE `char` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE account_id = " . $_GET['id'])
    or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
//aqui você fará um tratamento do erro se não der certo. Mostrar uma mensagem de erro amigável
//Esse die pode ser bom em casos de falha generalizada ou para testes
//mas nunca deveria ser usado em qualquer coisa séria.
```

Mas se quiser de forma mais segura pode fazer assim:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($db, "UPDATE `char` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE account_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/BasicQuery.php).

Recomendo fortemente rever seus código inseguros, todos eles. Eu percebo que você não se preocupa com isto, chega até colocar senhas expostas na internet.

Comment: Eu ja tenho feito esse redirecionamento para outra página, na qual eu boto mensagens para avisar se ocorreu tudo bem ou deu erro. O problema é que eu não sei o que botar na seguinte query: `$query = "UPDATE `tabela` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE name = ?";` pois eu não sei como fazer para ele pegar esse valor de name quando a pessoa clica no botao com o name desejado. Eu somente saberia fazer esse método se a pessoa digitasse o nome em um formulário, pois ficaria assim: `$query = "UPDATE `tabela` SET aparencia = '1' WHERE name = '".$_POST["name"]."'";` entende?

Comment: Sobre a tabela tirei um print para não ficar confuso: http://puu.sh/gYLVL/4083073484.png

Comment: @Guilherme como bigown falou, você troca o ID, pelo seu campo chave no caso pelo seu account_id e depois pode fazer seu SQL (exemplo): `$id = (int) $_GET['id']; UPDATE tabela SET aparecia='1' WHERE account_id = $id`;

Comment: Primeiro: se o `account_id` é - e eu desconfiava que era - sua chave primária, o código que você mostrou não está fazendo o que você diz fazer. Segundo: o que você está falando agora deixa a pergunta mais clara mas talvez não tão clara quanto deveria, isto deveria ter sido colocado nela, e ainda pode ser colocada. Se você tem o código do que você quer fazer quase pronto, é ele que você deve colocar. Terceiro: Sem saber como o `name` está chegando na página que fará a atualização, não dá para responder.

Comment: Então até o código que você colocou ajudaria elucidar isto, mas só ele ele mostrasse como ele está mandando a informação, o que não é o caso. Faça as edições necessárias e eu melhoro a resposta.

Comment: @bigown fiz as edições necessárias creio eu. Espero que assim fique mais fácil de entender o objetivo.

Comment: O código tem vários problemas. Você está aprendendo fazer as coisas tudo pela metade, aí você vai evoluindo errado e vai criando código cada vez mais esquisitos. Este é um problema generalizado que vai piorar cada dia que você insistir em fazer coisas novas sem entender como tudo funciona. Seguir receitas de bolo não costumam funcionar a não ser em coisas muitos simples, padronizadas ao extremo, e que a receita original seja muito boa. Não é o caso do que você está fazendo. Especificamente no foco do seu problema, entre outros problemas, está o fato da página tentar resolver muitas coisas.

Comment: Você deveria ter uma página para listar os personagens e outra página/*script* para fazer a atualização, mesmo que depois você chame de novo a página que liste os personagens novamente. Há um indicativo que você quer usar AJAX. Pode ser uma boa mesmo, e é mais um motivo para ter um *script* PHP separado para lidar com a alteração. Note que na pergunta original sequer havia essa intenção de usar AJAX e mesmo agora não está usando. Não vou focar nisto. Vou editar para melhor um pouco a resposta mas não acho que será a solução definitiva.

Comment: @bigown Sobre a não listagem dos personagens eu não entendi, pois eles estão perfeitamente listados: http://puu.sh/gYP33/1fcfe5852c.png Eu só não estou conseguindo entender sua resposta, pois você escreveu `Para listar os itens tem que colocar um link para este nome e chamar outra página para mostrá-lo.` mas como assim se eles já estão listados? Que senha que eu disponibilizei aqui no site? Só se estiver falando da senha do SQL do localhost... Eu sou bem iniciante por isso o código está ficando uma ganbiarra de coisas, se tu souber um método melhor para reestruturar o código por favor me envie

Comment: Eu também não entendi porque aparece, o código não parece fazer isto. Ou você está usando outra coisa ou ele está tão confuso que não deu para perceber isto acontecendo. O fato de você tentar fazer duas coisas ao mesmo tempo, não ajuda. Se está listado, está fazendo o que você quer? O problema era só o `UPDATE`? Então esquece essa parte. Eu acho que não está certo, mas como eu disse, sem resolver a confusão do seu código fica difícil até se comunicar. Eu sei um método melhor mas você precisará de um curso completo ou alguém fazer tudo para você.

Comment: O problema não é mais listar essa parte está funcionando perfeitamente. O objetivo agora seria ao clicar em cima do nome maria, atualizar a aparencia na tabela SQL onde o name seja maria para 1. Como eu escrevi na pergunta editada, se fosse com um método post seria ridiculo de fácil, porém agora usando botões ao invés de inputs type text eu não sei fazer entende?

Comment: Então, é o que eu coloquei na resposta. Realmente é muito fácil, pelo menos quando o código está organizado. A desorganização torna tudo mais difícil. Claro que eu tinha feito em cima do original. tente fazer primeiro com um *link* simples, depois pense em um botão. Como eu falei, separe os problemas. Esta pergunta é p/ resolver a questão da atualização do dado em cima da lista de personagens. Depois se ainda tiver problemas em fazer isto através de um botão, você faz outra pergunta pergunta, até porque para o banco de dados, não importa se é um botão ou não.

Comment: @bigown Editei a pergunta com o resultado do código atual. Creio ter feito as edições corretamente, porém ao clicar no nome nada acontece.

Comment: Eu faria assim e sei que funciona. O fato de não estar funcionando pode ser por inúmeros fatores e você teria que passar melhores informações para tentar descobrir o problema. Mas vi que você está usando o nome como uma informação canônica, o que é mais um problema na arquitetura do seu código. Tudo bem, não deve ser exatamente por causa disto que está acontecendo este problema (mas pode até ser), mas ele vai acabar causando outros problemas no futuro.

Comment: Levando em conta que cada account_id pode ter mais de um name, eu creio que essaa informação tem que ser atrelada à coluna name não seria?

Comment: A confusão já está aí, a tabela como um todo está esquisita. Eu nem entendo porque esta tabela está desta forma. Mas um nome como uma informação canônica nunca é uma boa ideia. Mas isto é outro problema. Eu não sei mais como ajudar nesta questão, eu dei a solução que funciona mas ela precisa ser aplicada corretamente. Eu não tenho como ajudar mais sem entender. Ou seja, essa pergunta já entro no problema de não estar clara ou ser muito ampla, porque eu só posso garantir que ela funcione se eu fizer toda esta parte do software para você.